# JS - Issue doing a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have case like this :

if nilai.value meet 7, i want to doing function like `$("#bt1").click(function()`. i try using this code, but failed. How to doing that?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 var ps = $('.z');
  $("#bt1").click(function(){
    var el1 = $("#pos7");
    var el2 = $("#neg7");
    ps.not(el1).slideUp()
    ps.not(el2).slideUp()
    el1.slideToggle();
    el2.slideToggle();
  });
  $('#slider').slider()
  .on('slide', function(ev){
  var nilai = document.getElementById('bar'); 
    if (nilai.value == 7)
    var el1 = $("#pos7");
    var el2 = $("#neg7");
    ps.not(el1).slideUp()
    ps.not(el2).slideUp()
        el1.slideToggle();
        el2.slideToggle();  
else if(nilai.value == 6)
          document.getElementById('amount').value ='sabtu';
         $('#bar').val(ev.value);
      });
    });
    </script>
```

sorry i am new in programming. in my mindset of case like above is just moving the code.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a block of statements, if you want to execute several statements when the condition in the [`if`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Statements#if...else_Statement) comes true. Something like this:

```
if (true) {
    statement1;
    statement2;
} else {
   stement1;
   statement2;
}
```

As its current form, your code executes all statements before `else` and then throws an error: `Else without if`.

When you get this fixed, you can move `$("#bt1").click(function(){...}` into that block.

Answer (score 0):

Try to correct your if else statements. They should look like this:

```
if () {
};
else if () {
};
else {};
```